# Buy a TV or a dedicated monitor

Tags: macbook-pro

I have 2012 model mac book air. At home i want to have a 22"-24" screen for work purpose. I was wondering if i should just buy a dedicated monitor or a 24" flatscreen tv with HDMI input? My work is generally  related to coding with some photo editing of family photos and watching movies. Also, are there any specific points which i need to consider while buying the monitor/tv so that it is compatible with my air.

Comment: Be sure to get HD resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, monitors have a higher pixel density because they are intended to be viewed for closer up. I'd recommend an HDMI, DVI or Display Port monitor because of the generally higher sharpness and contrast and more accurate colours over TVs.

Comment: + TVs tend to give you headaches if you look at them from the same distance as at a normal monitor... PC monitor all the way!

Answer (score 0):

Any device that takes HDMI as an input should work.

If you go for the TV option, it will also include speakers so if your Thunderbolt to HDMI converter sends out audio as well, it should go through to the speakers.

The best option is to go to a store and have a look at the different models. No all makes and models (both TV and screen) display colours equally well. Take some samples of what you would be working with and get them to display it on the screen to see what you prefer.

Also look at choosing LED over LCD as they use less power and tend to be better quality screens but can cost more.

Comment: LED screens ARE lcd… Typical LCD screens use a fluorescent backlight, an LED screen is an LCD screen with an LED based backlight.

Comment: Nonetheless, they are widely marketed under the terms 'LCD' (which usually means CCFL backlit) and 'LED' (for LED-backlit)-- for example: http://asia.cnet.com/led-vs-lcd-tv-which-is-better-62055838.htm. And LED-backlit LCDs displays *are* more power efficient then CCFL-backlit LCDs. So Alain is basically correct.

Answer (score 0):

For actual coding *work* you will need to be able to read what is on the monitor.  Anything less than full HD is waste of money for this purpose.

Then the question is about how close you will be to the monitor.  A 24" might actually be too big if you want it in about 40-60 cm's distance because you will need to move your head too much if you need to see it all.

That said, any modern HDMI unit should be usable.  Buy the adapter and go down in the store and see what it looks like.  REMEMBER to disable any image enhancements designed to improve on a low quality tv-signal.